# Laravel/homestead failed to work in mac os

Tags: laravel, homestead

when I input "test.app” in the browser ，the browser can not connect to it.
In the installation of the homestead,I failed to install it with the command

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

or

```
composer global require"laravel/homestead=~2.0"
```

I used this command

```
cd ~git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead
```

So I am not sure if I have succeed to fix the homestead

Another question is that my Vagrantfile's floders can't sync like it should be.

Comment: This could help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35653573/laravel-homestead-vagrant-not-working/35679297#35679297

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make few steps to make it work:

- Make sure vagrant and VirtualBox are installed on your computer.
- Did you run bash `init.sh`? It will create .yaml file for you.
- Edit .yaml file like in manual  (don't forget to generate ssh key and setup folders).
- Put this into your `/etc/hosts` file: `192.168.10.10 test.app`
- run VM with running `vagrant up` command in terminal

  You'll see Laravel 5 start page, if you made everything like in the manual:
  https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead#installation-and-setup

Comment: How to make sure vagrant has been installed on my computer?when I "vagrant ssh",I found the php and mysql had been installed ,so can I regard this as the mark of the success to install?

Comment: When you use `vagrant ssh`, it should run SSH client for you or give an error. Also, `vagrant up` will run vagrant VM (you'll see a lot of messages) or it will give you same error like 'vagrant command not found'.

Comment: when I use "vagrant up"and"vagrant ssh",everything is ok.But I just used the command git clone .How could that happen!

Comment: Great! If you try to access http://192.168.10.10 in browser, do you see Laravel start page?

Comment: That's where I confused with.I failed to access 192.168.10.10.

Comment: When I try to install homestead with composer,I got such error"An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again."

SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 54

Comment: Well, if `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh` works, but you can't access 192.168.10.10 after ran `vagrant up` successfully, the problem is with configuration. Look at 2 and 3 steps in my post.

Comment: what did generate ssh key mean?Did it will lead to the failure to access the network?

Comment: From documentation: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "you@homestead"` for the mac, then you should put path to it into `Homestead.yaml`

Comment: @zyMacro, if my answer was helpful, please choose it as best answer if you want to thank me for my time.